# selenium 3.0 not working on firefox49 using marionette

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

i am using selenium 3.0 version with python 2.7 binding. when i tried to launch code on firefox 49 it throws an exception following is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX


firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True


binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

geckodriver="/Users/pmarques/Test/geckodriver"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, executable_path="C:\\python code\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Error Found is

```
C:\python code>python testfirefox.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfirefox.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", lin
e 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", lin
e 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unex
pectedly exited. Status code was: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the driver in one command

```
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=caps, executable_path="C:\\python code\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe")
```